# Scheduled Apex not making changes

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I am attempting to use the following code to make scheduled changes to 10 records every day. The scheduler kicks it off, but no changes are ever made. I've looked at the records and they're not modified.

Here is the code :

```
public class WeeklyMailerOpp implements Schedulable
{
    public void execute (SchedulableContext scx)
    {


        List<Mailer__c> records = [
            SELECT Name, OwnerId, Distributed__c FROM Mailer__c
            WHERE Distributed__c = false LIMIT 10
        ];
        for(Mailer__c record : records)
        {
            record.Distributed__c = true;

        }
        update records;
    }
}
```

Why would my records not get updated?

Comment: What do the debug logs show? Were there any exceptions/limits encountered that would have caused the transaction to roll back?

Comment: Does the user account running the scheduled job have access to the `Mailer__c `records where the `Distributed__c` field is false?

Comment: Yes - the user running the job has access. It's me and I created the object and documents.

Comment: Well, I set up the debug logs, ran the scheduler, and was ready to combing through the logs - and it worked ! No idea what happened ! Thanks for help anyway @DanielBallinger. I appreciate it.

Comment: Did the scheduled job run as the same user?

Comment: Yes it did. It shows me as the modifier. I was thinking access might have been causing problems with it as well. That's why I took out some of the code which was originally making a queue the Owner. But I had already run it once without the queue portion of the code and it didn't work. But it worked this time. I dunno.